# meta tag name viewport not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a site mobile friendly by using meta tag name viewport.

I tried the following syntax, which didn't seem to work:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

It worked at one point when I copied the line from a website that had used a different style quotation mark. (I don't remember which website)
Closing the editor and reopening my editor I noticed that the quotation mark at the end changed into a question mark as below

```
<meta  name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 ?>
```

It was working using a question mark without any problems initially, however the next day when I reopened the document from FTP and reloaded the page, I noticed that it was not working with the question mark anymore.

I dont know where I copied the initial meta tag viewport command that was working with the different style quotation mark initially to test if that works anymore or not.

Can anyone provide advise why this might not be working and how I can troubleshoot it to get it working?

I would also like to be able to get the following code Javascript code working which I was unable to get working. If there is any advice on this as well, that would be great

```
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">');
```

Additional Information
Found Firebug to be a troubleshooting tool. Looked at the code firebug is giving.
Firebug seems to have change the meta tag name viewport line into

```
<meta content-type"="" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0? > <meta http-equiv=" name="viewport">
```

Comment: What's not working? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`

Comment: don't use it dynamically over javascript. The rendering engine for browsers using it at initial loading; If you set it after content is loaded, it seems not to be working.

Comment: The following line is not working first i want to get this working <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> The web address i have uploaded it to is www.ictlds.co.uk

Comment: That line with the question mark makes no sense whatsoever. Besides, you have not told us what “nor working” actually means here.

Comment: Slime i have entered the code as you specified <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> however it still not taking into account and firebug is showing the line as <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">

Comment: CBroe it was a different style quotation mark copied from a web page can't remember. When I was doing more copying and pasting from different sites with standard quotation marks replacing the original line it was not taking it into account. I then found out it was because the quotation mark was dfferent style. Cant understand why that is myself. But when i closed my editor and reopened the editor it changed into a question mark. uploading it as a question mark initially worked but is now not working.

Comment: the following line is not working <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> This line should make it suited for mobile content. It did work as explained above but now not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'll address two issues here.

Firstly, the question mark in the code. I'd wager a bet that this came from someone accidentally formatting their blog article with 'smart quotes' so the final quote character became a Unicode Closing Double Quote quote character, which has ended up rendering as ? because of an encoding conflict somewhere. Basically, retype it with proper double quotes to fix it.

Secondly, as Adrian said in the commends, using JS to dynamically add the meta tags after load is unlikely to work. Browsers will look for this key information while they're reading in the initial content stream, similarly to checking for page encoding and doctype.

*One additional note for you: on your current home page, www.ictlds.co.uk, you have illegal closing tags for your meta description and keywords. A meta tag is self-closing so you must not add a closing tag. Run your page through the W3C Validator service.*